# Most efficient way to determine if a Lua table is empty (contains no entries)?

Tags: lua, lua-table

What's the most efficient way to determine if a table is empty (that is, currently contains neither array-style values nor dict-style values)?

Currently, I'm using `next()`:

```
if not next(myTable) then
    -- Table is empty
end
```

Is there a more efficient way?

Note: The `#` operator does not suffice here, as it only operates on the array-style values in the table - thus `#{test=2}` is indistinguishable from `#{}` because both return 0. Also note that checking if the table variable is `nil` does not suffice as I am not looking for nil values, but rather tables with 0 entries (i.e. `{}`).

Answer (score 221, accepted):

Your code is efficient but wrong.  (Consider `{[false]=0}`.)  The correct code is

```
if next(myTable) == nil then
   -- myTable is empty
end
```

For maximum efficiency you'll want to bind `next` to a local variable, e.g.,

```
...
local next = next 
...
... if next(...) ...
```

(When `next` is local, the code finds primitive function `next` by a constant-time indexing operation into an array of "upvalues."  When `next` is left global, finding `next` involves indexing index the "environment" hash table, which contains the values of the global variables.  This indexing operation is still constant-time, but it is significantly slower than the array lookup for a local variable.)

Comment: Good point on the technical correctness; in the particular cases I've been utilizing the original code, `false` wouldn't be an expected key so the `if not` worked fine, but I'll probably make a habit of comparing to `nil` instead in the future, just as a good habit. And yes, I've been binding common utility functions to local vars for speed. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: I find it hard to agree with wrongness when the code works as intended

Comment: Why do we gain speed by doing `local next`?

Comment: @Moberg This is due to how LUA handles its namespace. The very dumbed down version, is it will first climb up the local tables, so if there is a `local next` in the current block, it will use that, then climb up to the next block, and repeat. Once out of locals, it will only then use the Global Namespace. This is a dumbed down version of it, but in the end, it definitely means the difference in regards to program speed.

Comment: @Moberg the less dumbed down version, in the context of lua 5.2 & 5.3, is that non locals are either upvals or _ENV lookups. An upval has to go through an extra layer of indirection, whereas an _ENV lookup is a table lookup. Whereas a local is a register in the VM

Comment: @Moberg at run time a global variable requires a hash-table lookup but a `local` variable requires only an array lookup.

Comment: @NormanRamsey the "local" binding will only improve performance if you use the binding more than once, correct? if you use it only once, then in both cases you'll have one global lookup, but on one case you'll have a local variable binding as well.

Comment: Question, why is faster the " == nil" than "if not"?

Comment: @HerlySQR It's not faster, it's more correct. `if not` will miss one case where the table is not empty, as described in the answer, for the table `{[false]=0}`. `next()` returns the key, which is `false` in that example, and `if not false` will mislead you into thinking the table is empty. The `== null` approach will work correctly even in that case.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to count the number of elements, by using the metatable "newindex" key. When assigning something not `nil`, increment the counter (the counter could live in the metatable as well) and when assigning `nil`, decrement the counter.

Testing for empty table would be to test the counter with 0.

Here's a pointer to [metatable documentation](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.8)

I do like your solution though, and I honestly can't assume that my solution is faster overall.

Comment: The original question is not about counting just "array" entries.

Comment: 0x6's suggestion isn't specific to array-style entries (newindex works for both numerical and non-numerical indices). However, the main issue would be detecting when `nil` is assigned, since __newindex does not trigger if the key already exists in the table.

Comment: For this trick to work, the metatable would have to implement both `__index` and `__newindex`, storing the actual data in a shadow table and keeping the real table empty so that `__index` will be invoked at all. Thinking out loud, I suspect that the raised cost of every single lookup can't be worth it.

Answer (score 1):

better to avoid the evaluation of __eq if overloaded.

```
if rawequal(next(myTable), nil) then
   -- myTable is empty
end
```

or

```
if type(next(myTable)) == "nil" then
   -- myTable is empty
end
```

Comment: I'm a Lua noob trying to understand why this answer was down voted. I'm guessing it is because in Lua, "if two objects have different metamethods, the equality operation results in false, without even calling any metamethod". (The quote is at the bottom of [this page from Programming in Lua on lua.org](https://www.lua.org/pil/13.2.html) ). Does that remove the need to avoid __eq overloading for nil?

Comment: SansWit: Yes, it does.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you wanted:

```
function table.empty (self)
    for _, _ in pairs(self) do
        return false
    end
    return true
end

a = { }
print(table.empty(a))
a["hi"] = 2
print(table.empty(a))
a["hi"] = nil
print(table.empty(a))
```

Output:

```
true
false
true
```

Comment: `next()` is more efficient (and more concise) than looping over `pairs()`.

Comment: In fact, looping over `pairs()` *is* essentially just using the `next()` technique, but with more overhead.

Comment: Also, writing into the standard `table` library is not recommended.

Answer (score -4):

try serpent, work for me

```
serpent = require 'serpent'

function vtext(value)
  return serpent.block(value, {comment=false})
end

myTable = {}

if type(myTable) == 'table' and vtext(myTable) == '{}' then
   -- myTable is empty
end
```

Answer (score -5):

I know this is old, and I could be misunderstanding you somehow, but it you just want the table to be empty, that is, unless you are just checking if it is and you don't actually want or need it to be empty, you can clear it by simply recreating it, unless I'm mistaken. this can be done with the below syntax.

```
yourtablename = {} -- this seems to work for me when I need to clear a table.
```

Comment: That's not the question.

Answer (score -6):

How about this ?

```
if endmyTable[1] == nil then
  -- myTable is empty
end
```

Comment: This won't work on a table that as strings as index's

Comment: Or a table that doesn't have a value at index `1`. Consider `{[2] = true}`

Answer (score -10):

Try using `#`. It returns all the instances that are in a table. If there aren't instances in a table,then it returns `0`

```
if #myTable==0 then
print('There is no instance in this table')
end
```

Comment: The asker says that `#` won't suffice here, and gives reasons why; could you explain why this gets around those reasons?

Comment: well...i don't know.I am new in this so the only way i know is using #

Comment: `#` only works on contiguous arrays which begin at index `1`. The following tables won't work: `{a=true}`, `{[2]=true}`.